# Flash v11.8.800.168 function call fails in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, firefox

Company recently upgraded to Flash v11.8.800.168 and a flash movie which is loaded using SWFObject (1.1) is not working correctly in Internet Explorer (Firefox works fine).  The movie is loaded dynamically using a jquery document.ready method using the "new SWFObject(...); so.write("ID")" method (again SWFObject 1.1).\

The movie on load calls a JavaScript function (which is built dynamically using server scripting).  The function is being called correctly as checked by a debugger.  The JavaScript function calls a method in the flash movie passing it some XML (which is used to render some user and navigation items).

Something like this:

```
function calledFromFlash() {
 document.getElementById("FlashMovie").renderUsingXml('<?xml version 1.0"?><lotsofxml></lotsofxml>');
}
```

Like I said, this all works still in Firefox with the new Flash version.

When I step through the function above, using step into with the IE Debugger, I get the following steps:

```
function anonymous() {
    return eval(this.CallFunction("<invoke name=\"renderUsingXml\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments, 0) + "</invoke>"));
}
```

At this point, I checked the arguments variable and it contains the XML as one would expect.  After the next step into, I get this:

```
try { __flash__toXML(calledFromFlash(undefined)); } catch (e) { "<undefined/>"; }
```

At this point the debugger is already on the catch, yet one more step into take the code into the "<undefined/>" section and I can see that **e** is **Object Expected**

What I've tried:

- Static implementation without SWFObject. This works. But then Firefox doesn't process the XML properly (and it seems to be the same issue as IE)
- Upgrading to SWFObject 2.2.  Using dynamic implementation it fails still.  Using static implementation it works in IE but not Firefox

This is NOT my flash movie, the source is... well, I don't know.  The guy that wrote it has left the company.  That said, this seems like such a crazy issue.

My proposed fix is simply to use SWFObject for Firefox and use a static implementation for IE, but I really want to know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in Flash Player 11.8.800.168.  It has been fixed in 11.8.800.175.

Bug fixes:

```
3630443 - [External][Windows][IE] ExternalInterface.call() method with non-ASCII text as a parameter corrupts the characters on the Javascript side
```

Comment: See also [bug #3630370](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3630370)